# Configure Launchpad OSX Lion

Tags: macos, launchpad

How to configure launchpad on OSX Lion?
Like

1. Hide some application
2. Group application into folder
3. Sort application alphabetical

Comment: You are asking three different questions, and while they are related, each question has a different answer. It works best on Ask Different if you ask a single question in a post.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! As @Daniel says, you have multiple questions here. On this site, things really work better if you ask each question individually. That way, it's easier for people with the same problem to search on this site and find the answer. Please feel free to ask these questions separately. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lion’s LaunchPad acts much like iOS’ Springboard (the iDevice home screen launcher), which means that

1. you can create folders by dragging one Launchpad app icon onto another – add more items by dragging them onto the newly created folder. Folders can be renamed by clicking their title when opened. They cannot be nested.
2. you can [only sort items by dragging them around](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3208907).
3. hiding apps is not a feature (there is a closing cross on App Store installed apps when you press Option, but this uninstalls the app – it does not hide it from Launchpad). Use [Launchpad-Control](http://chaosspace.de/launchpad-control/) (freeware) to achieve that.